# Vue prop assignment string concat returns NaN

Tags: vuejs2

This is just a very simple Vue code but I can't get it to work.

```
<input type="text" :class="'required-class' + custom_class" />
```

and my props is

```
props:{
    custom_class:{type:String}
      }
```

expected output:

```
<input type="text" class="required-class some-class-submitted" />
```

but returns:

```
<input type="text" class="NaN some-class-submitted" />
```

P.S I'm aware I can achieve this using the `computed` property, but is there any simpler solution without using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot bind to the `class` property that way, instead do this:
`<input type="text" class="required-class"  :class="[custom_class] " />`

I recomend you read the documentation for binding classes and styles it is very well explained there https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html